# Undefined method for backoffice controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have products and 2 controllers associated with them.
In one (products_controller.rb) there are only index and show methods.
The other (backoffice / products_controller.rb) has all the CRUD methods.
And when I want to use the create or destroy methods in backoffice / products_controller.rb I get an error that these methods are not available in products_controller.rb.
Methods index and show work correctly.

For example, how I use the Destroy method in backoffice/products_controller

```rb
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render 'destroy', status: :destroy, location: @product }
      format.html { redirect_to admin_products_path, notice: 'Product was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

And how i call this method (views/backoffice/product):

```rb
<%= link_to (fa_icon "trash"), product,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "pull-right btn btn-outline-danger" %>
```

error - `The action 'destroy' could not be found for ProductsController`

routes:

```rb
  scope '/admin' do
    resources :categories, controller: 'backoffice/categories', as: "admin_categories"
    resources :products, controller: 'backoffice/products', as: "admin_products"
  end
```

**UPD**
form:

```rb
<div class="container main">

  <%= form_with(model: product, local: true) do |form| %>

  <div class="field">
  <%= form.collection_select(:category_id, Category.all, :id, :title, class:'form-control' ) %>
</div>

  <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :title %>
      <%= form.text_field :title, class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :description %>
    <%= form.text_area :description, class: "form-control"%>
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="text-center actions">
    <%= form.submit 'Submit', class: "btn btn-dark" %>
  </div>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the generated HTML, you will find that:

```
<%= link_to (fa_icon "trash"), product,  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "pull-right btn btn-outline-danger" %>
```

...resolves to the `ProductsController` (something like `products/1`), not the `Backoffice::ProductsController` (something like `backoffice/products/1`). You'll probably want to do something more like:

```
<%= link_to (fa_icon "trash"), admin_product_path(product),  method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' }, class: "pull-right btn btn-outline-danger" %>
```

In your form, you'll want to do something like:

```
<%= form_with(model: product, local: true, url: admin_products_path) do |form| %>
```

You may or may not need to fiddle with that `url` bit. See [the docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_with).

Comment: And what should I change in my form so that method create also works? :)